# Cannot protect laravel pulse route

Tags: php, laravel

Recently Laravel Pulse was released and yesterday I installed it. The problem I have is that I can't protect the route correctly.

I followed the documentation and added the Gate in the AuthServiceProvider, but it's not working, I can access it anyway no matter what, it's like it never accesses that part of the code.

Also, I don't know how it works the fact that it is the path /pulse where the Dashboard is rendered, how/where can I change that?

What can it be?

This is how my AuthServiceProvider looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Gate::define('viewPulse', function (User $user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
               'dev@as.com'
            ]);
        });
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `AuthServiceProvider.php` look like?

Comment: Your local environment is exempt from Pulse authorization checks. Check the value of `APP_ENV` in `.env` or `config('app.env')`. If it's `local`, your Gate will be ignored. To test it, you can change environment names to something like `not-local`.

Comment: @Alex I updated the original post.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just changed my env file but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Make sure your config isn't cached. `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Still not working D:

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, what does `config('app.env')` result in?

Comment: 'production' (used to be local, then changed to 'not-local' and then to 'production')

Comment: Can you add a `dd(1)` inside your gate function to check if the function is even called?

Comment: @Alex I'ts not!

Comment: @mushulmao is the AuthServiceProvider listed in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @Alex yes it is! The only way I found to make the authorization work is to add some middleware in config/pulse.php, but if I do that I can no longer access it from where I normally do which is localhost/pulse. I also don't understand how I connect this to the front end? I mean, if my home path on the frontend is localhost:3003/home, how do I access it as localhost:3003/pulse? It's so confusing D:

Comment: @mushulmao I dont know about pulse specifically. Have you setup a regular laravel project before? You define routes and groups and you can apply middlewares to it, like an auth provider. I suggest reading the docs or a tutorial on laravel or maybe edit your question because right now it seems you are just unfamiliar with the laravel framework or at least I dont understand what you mean by home and frontend routes.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and after a thorough investigation, I discovered that the authorization logic requires the presence of a user.

To utilize the `viewPulse` ability, you must indicate that you allow the user to be null.

```php
Gate::define('viewPulse', static function (?User $user) {
    return true;  // Replace with your actual authorization logic
});
```

Important part `?User $user`.